# Copying a directory which is outside a docker to a container inside a docker

Tags: docker-container

How to copy a directory to a container in a docker, where the directory is outside the docker?

Comment: you should be abled to do that using ```ADD``` command https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#add

Answer (score 2):

Use the `docker cp` command to achieve that. It work both ways from and to your docker container.

Please see the docker documentation here: [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#description).

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

---

To copy file from local to a docker container:

```
docker cp local.file Container_ID:/distination/inside/myDockerContrainer
```

To copy file from a container to your local storage:

```
docker cp Container_ID:/file/inside/myDockerContrainer local.file
```

Comment: Good answer.  I made a few structural edits to you answer: removing the shell symbol `$`, adding a link description, and fixing some of the code formatting.  For some reason code formatting in a list context doesn't always look correct.  Please feel free to re-edit your question if I went a bit too far.